# Integral of the product of two Sine Functions Evaluated at Regular Intervals = 2 * Num. of Intervals Used?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Basically the I am considering the sum of the product of two sine functions:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} sin(2 \pi {1\over N} k) sin(2 \pi {1 \over N }k)$$

I am trying to make sense of the the case when you multiply these two sine functions at 8 regular intervals (say at t = 0, t = 1/8, t = 2/8 ... up to say t = 7/8) and add up all the results together. With 8 intervals, the result is 16.

I am trying to make sense of this. Could someone explain please why evaluating the functions like this, and adding up the result gives two times the number of intervals used?

How does the equation is used above would relate to (EDIT I mean by that I know the integral is supposed to represent the area under the curve defined by the function in this case the product of two sine functions but how shall I interpret the result of the equation above?):

$$\int_{t=0}^{t=1} sin(2 \pi t) sin(2 \pi t) dt.$$

It would be great if someone could help. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you are backwards.  It should be half the number of intervals-as $\sin x$ is always less than or equal to one in absolute value, the summands are always between $0$ and $1$

Comment: Yes you are right, not sure where I made mistake before... sorry maybe I should correct the title of the post. It's 4 indeed and just using your brain to find this is a lesson for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the general identity $\sin^2 x=\frac 12(1-\cos(2x))$  If you do the sum at evenly spaced points through the period, the points where the cosine is positive will cancel with other points where the cosine is negative, so the sum will be one half the number of points, or $\frac N2$.  It works the same way for the integral, and for the same reason.